# Play JSON formatter for case class with generic type classes

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

Trying to write a json formatter for this case class

```
case class OptionRange[+T](start: Option[T], end: Option[T])
```

This is what I have so far

```
implicit def fmt[T <: OptionRange[_]](implicit fmt: Format[Option[T]]): Format[OptionRange[T]] = new Format[OptionRange[T]] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsSuccess[OptionRange[T]] = JsSuccess(new OptionRange[T] (
    (json \ "start").as[Option[T]],
    (json \ "end").as[Option[T]]
  ))
  def writes(i: OptionRange[T]) = JsObject(Seq(
    "start" -> Json.toJson(i.start),
    "end" -> Json.toJson(i.end)
  ))
}
```

This piece of code compiles but when I try to format an `OptionRange[Int]` I get an error that there is no implicit format available.

How can I write a format that will be available in the implicit scope?

Comment: note that `.as[Option[T]]` is not the idiomatic way to do it in Play-Json. `.readNullable[T]` is preferable. It is automatically going to lift your `T` in the `Option`

Comment: Actually @LouisF.  `.readNullable[T]` is a method that is available on `JsPath` and not `JsValue`... please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You have a bit of a cyclical type definition going on.

It looks to me like you are intending `T` to be evaluated as `Int` in this case. However, in the function definition, you've constrained `[T <: OptionRange[_]]`. So, Scala thinks that `T` must be an `OptionRange` of something.

This gets further complicated when you go to your implicit parameter for the function, `(implicit fmt: Format[Option[T]])`. If `T` is `OptionRange[_]`, then you are telling the compiler to require a `Format[Option[OptionRange[_]]]` instead of a `Format[Option[_]]`. Your function can't be the source of that `Format`, since it can't be evaluated in order to provide the implicit required.

The solution is to stop constraining `T`.

```
implicit def fmt[T](implicit fmt: Format[Option[T]]) ...
```

Then, when you try to format an `OptionRange` as json:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> case class OptionRange[+T](start: Option[T], end: Option[T])
defined class OptionRange

scala> implicit def fmt[T](implicit fmt: Format[Option[T]]): Format[OptionRange[T]] = new Format[OptionRange[T]] {
     |   def reads(json: JsValue): JsSuccess[OptionRange[T]] = JsSuccess(new OptionRange[T] (
     |     (json \ "start").as[Option[T]],
     |     (json \ "end").as[Option[T]]
     |   ))
     |   def writes(i: OptionRange[T]) = JsObject(Seq(
     |     "start" -> Json.toJson(i.start),
     |     "end" -> Json.toJson(i.end)
     |   ))
     | }
fmt: [T](implicit fmt: play.api.libs.json.Format[Option[T]])play.api.libs.json.Format[OptionRange[T]]

scala> Json.toJson(OptionRange(Some(1), Some(2)))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"start":1,"end":2}
```

Comment: Can you let me know everything you typed into the console? I can't replicate what you have be able to. Also, which version of play-json did you use?

Comment: @adamtrousdale I believe I'm using v2.3.8 of play-json. However, that shouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: @adamtrousdale Also, I updated my answer to have the code that I typed into the scala console.

Comment: I don't get the same in my console, i get `scala> Json.toJson(OptionRange(Some(1), Some(2)))
<console>:22: error: No Json serializer found for type OptionRange[Int]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
       Json.toJson(OptionRange(Some(1), Some(2)))`

Comment: Could you show me somehow exactly what you're typing and seeing in the scala console after every entry? Have you tried specifying `fmt` manually without leaving it up to implicit resolution?

Comment: Type `scala> import play.api.libs.json._`, see `import play.api.libs.json._`

Comment: Type `scala> case class OptionRange[+T](start: Option[T], end: Option[T])`, see `defined class OptionRange`

Comment: Type ```implicit def fmt[T](implicit fmt: Format[Option[T]]): Format[OptionRange[T]] = new Format[OptionRange[T]] {
def reads(json: JsValue): JsSuccess[OptionRange[T]] = JsSuccess(new OptionRange[T] (
 (json \ "start").as[Option[T]],
     (json \ "end").as[Option[T]]
   ))
   def writes(i: OptionRange[T]) = JsObject(Seq(
     "start" -> Json.toJson(i.start),
     "end" -> Json.toJson(i.end)
   ))
 }```, see `error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Json.class'.`

Comment: apologies the formatting is poor. After I import the `Json.class` from `play.api.libs.api.json` I then get another error and have to import the `Writes.class`. Then when trying to define my formatter I get an error saying that the class file `Reads.class` is missing. After importing and trying to define again I get a missing `JsResult.class` error. After importing that I can then define my formatter successfully. Trying to do `Json.toJson(OptionRange(Some(1), Some(2)))` however still results in the same error above `No Json serializer found`

Comment: It seems like this should be working without getting any of these issues around the missing classes etc

Comment: That is incredibly strange. What is the proper import that you need to perform, then? Have those classes been moved in your version of play-json?

Comment: It's very strange, I can't work out why I have to import these classes individually. I have tried with play-json 2.3.8 but had the same issues. What I had to do was import each class (`Json.class`, `Writes.class`, `Reads.class`, `JsResult.class`), each in the play.api.libs.json package but not imported with the first import statement `import play.api.libs.json._`

Comment: How does it behave if you modify your actual code, rather than trying to do it in a Scala console?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this using play-framework `2.3.9`, Scala `2.11.8`:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._ // JSON library
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._ // Custom validation helpers
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._ // Combinator syntax

case class OptionRange[+T](start: Option[T], end: Option[T])

object Hello extends App {

  implicit def formatOptionRange[T](implicit formatT: Format[T]): Format[OptionRange[T]] = 
    (
      (JsPath \ "start").formatNullable[T] and
      (JsPath \ "end").formatNullable[T]
    )(OptionRange.apply, unlift(OptionRange.unapply))

    println(Json.toJson(OptionRange(Some(1), Some(2))))
}

//Prints:
//{"start":1,"end":2}
```

Here is the documentation on [format](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Format).